# Getting error "Cannot satisfy query -- too many IN/!= values". How to solve this?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Problem: User(B) needs help from a set of Users(A) based on certain criteria. This criteria is set by Users(A) in their profile.

```
class UsersAProfiles(db.Model):
    industries = db.StringListProperty()  #technology, etc. (total 20)
    agegroups  = db.StringListProperty()  #teenagers, etc. (total 10)
    tags       = db.StringListProperty()  #cooking, etc.
    (while each User A can enter at most 10 tags, but there is no limit on 
     what tags are used, e.g., sql, gym, etc. (limited by dictionary!)
    ...                                   #there are many other properties
```

User(B)'s sets the criteria that is stored separately

```
class UserBRequestForHelp(db.Model):
    myindustries = db.StringListProperty()  #technology, etc. (<20)
    myagegroups  = db.StringListProperty()  #teenagers, etc. (<10)
    mytags       = db.StringListProperty()  #cooking, etc.
    ...                                     #there are many other properties
```

Now I need list of all Users A that can potentially help B. For that I try to run the following query:

```
query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM UsersAProfiles WHERE 
        industries IN :1 AND 
        agegroups  IN :2 AND
        tags       IN :3", 
        userB_obj.myindustries , userB_obj.myagegroups, userB_obj.mytags)
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Cannot satisfy query -- too many IN/!= values.
```

I am really stuck here and don't know how to solve this problem. How to run such queries. Furthermore, do I need to design the model classes differently so that I can run such queries? If yes, could someone please help.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problems like above, the following approach may be useful.

1. List TAGS in a separate model with list of all matching UserA profiles.

   ```
   class TAGS(db.Model):
       UserAIds  = db.StringListProperty()
   ```

   In the above, each tag is the key. (tag = technology, teenagers, cooking, etc.)
2. When User B sets the criteria, then to find matching Users A, the queries that we can run are as follows:

   ```
   i = 0
   for industry in userB_obj.myindustries:
         t1_obj[i] = TAGS.get_by_key_name(industry)
         i = i + 1
   ```

   (in the above t1_obj[i] you have list of User A profiles that have matching industries)

   ```
   j = 0
   for agegroup in userB_obj.myagegroups:
         t2_obj[j] = TAGS.get_by_key_name(agegroup)
         j = j + 1
   ```

   (in the above t2_obj[j] you have list of User A profiles that have matching agegroups)

   ```
   k = 0
   for tag in userB_obj.mytags:
         t3_obj[k] = TAGS.get_by_key_name(tag)
         k = k + 1
   ```

   (in the above t3_obj[k] you have list of User A profiles that have matching tags)
3. Next, all you need to do is find UserA profiles that are present in ALL three, i.e., t1_obj, t2_obj, t3_obj and that's all!
   Now to find UserA profiles that are present in all 3 above, not sure if there is a python function that can do that. But, using model instances you can solve it as follows

   ```
   class MatchingUserAs(db.Model):
         count  = db.IntegerProperty(default=0) 
         source = db.StringProperty(default=None)
   ```

   (in the above model class, UserA id is the key. This UserAids are stored in t1_key[i].UserAIds, t2_key[j].UserAids, t3_key[k].UserAIds)
4. Now, loop through t1_obj[i], t2_obj[j], t3_obj[k] and insert UserA id in MatchingUserAs and increment the count by 1 each time you insert a row / update a row.

   ```
   <"loop through t1_obj[i]">:
         Matchkey = MatchingUserAs.get_or_insert(t1_obj[i].UserAId)
         Matchkey.count = 1
         Matchkey.source = 'industry'
         Matchkey.put()

   <"loop through t2_obj[j]">:
         Matchkey = MatchingUserAs.get_or_insert(t2_obj[j].UserAId)
         #the following if check has been added to avoid incrementing the counter
         #when same UserAid is present in, say, t2_obj[0], and t2_obj[1], etc.
         if(Matchkey.source != 'agegroup')
             Matchkey.count  = Matchkey.count + 1
             Matchkey.source = 'agegroup'
         Matchkey.put()

   <"loop through t3_obj[j]">:
         Matchkey = MatchingUserAs.get_or_insert(t3_obj[j].UserAId)
         if(Matchkey.source != 'tags')
             Matchkey.count  = Matchkey.count + 1
             Matchkey.source = 'tags'
         Matchkey.put()
   ```
5. Now, all you need to do is fetch those UserAs from MatchingUserAs with a count of 3 (because there are 3 list of tags that we want to match: industries, agegroups, and tags).

There may be some syntax errors in above code samples especially for keys and objects usage; and in some cases pseudocode has been used. I just wanted to give an overview of the solution. Hope this helps. Feel free to share any comments.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a query using IN, GAE has to break that query into a number of "index = value" subqueries, executing each and collecting the results assembling them as though they had been one search.  There is a limit to the number of subqueries that a query can expand out to, and [that limit is 30](https://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/detail?id=160).  If you're creating queries with 31 subqueries, that would explain why you are running into this.  In other words, your situation is that len(userB_obj.myindustries) + len(userB_obj.myagegroups) + len(userB_obj.mytags) > 30.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Greatly appreciate it. I was also wondering what the solution should be. (just came up with an alternative solution (slept thinking about the solution and let the subconscious mind work over it last night :-)). Will post the answer soon. Thank again for the information!